# Of the millions of transistors in a typical microprocessor, what percentage of them are BJTs and MOFSETS?

Tags: transistors

This is broad in the sense of which microprocessor I am referring to. I expect them to be similar, but if not, then how about in an Intel 7th gen CPU and in an A11 iPhone chip?

And what about how many MOFSETS/BJTs in an entire iPhone(let's say 10X)? Are BJTs used at all?

I am curious to know the distribution due to the notion of MOSFETs being much preferred for switching purposes. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a microprocessor: **ZERO**. All modern processors use CMOS logic.

Reasons why:

- CMOS transistors can be made much-much smaller than BJTs, that means cheaper chips and more functionality per chip
- CMOS logic is much more power efficient than logic made with BJTs
- When CMOS logic is static (no state changes like when in standby) current consumption can be almost **zero**. This is impossible to do with BJT based logic.
- CMOS manufacturing processes are generally **simpler** (less processing steps) than processes with BJTs. This means lower manufacturing costs.
- If your Iphone used BJT based logic for everything then it would need to be **as large as a truck**, half of which would need to be reserved for the battery or generator and fuel.

BJTs **are often used** in **high frequency** circuits like the circuits that connect to the antennas. There is a trend to use CMOS transistors for this as well so what is used depends on price and what performance is needed.

What is used in a particular phone can only be answered by the designers or you'd need to reverse engineer the phone. You would need a well equipped lab to do that and specialists to analyze the chips. Many chips will be unmarked and even if you would know the model number of a chip then it might not be clear if it uses any BJTs inside.

Comment: Although the original Intel Pentium used the BiCMOS process, where BJT and CMOS where combined to used the advantges of both technologies.

Comment: @jusaca Indeed "the advantges of both technologies" but you should add: "with the technology that was available at the time". In IC process technology respect, the original Intel Pentium uses a 0.8 μm BiCMOS process which is **ancient** technology by today's standards for complex logic chips. The Pentium had to be able to connect to 5 V TTL chips so that's why they had to use BJTs. Later all chips on a PC motherboard used CMOS so support for 5 V TTL was not needed anymore.

Comment: Some devices that have internal temperature sensors (for external measurement) have a diode connected bipolar (sometimes a few for different regions) but as you note these are not part of the processing core.